# Rewrite nginx url

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, nginx-config

I am facing problem with rewriting url in nginx.
The issue is if the url contains domain/.well-known/acme-challenge/ it should be replaced by domain/folder/.well-known/acme-challenge.
How can I rewrite nginx for this so that it points to proper location.

The request for the nginx configuration works with this url:
domain/folder/.well-known/acme-challenge
but I want it to redirect when it finds something like
domain/.well-known/acme-challenge/

Here is my nginx conf:-

```
#upstream jboss {
#    server domain:8080;
#}

server {
  listen       ip:80;
  server_name  domain;

 access_log  /var/log/nginx/domian_access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/domain_error.log warn;

#    location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
#    expires 365d;
#}

    location /folder/ {

       # ModSecurityEnabled on;
       # ModSecurityConfig modsecurity.conf;

        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   #     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
   #     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;

        proxy_pass http://ip:8080/folder/;
  proxy_connect_timeout       6000;
  proxy_send_timeout          6000;
  proxy_read_timeout          6000;
  send_timeout                6000;

        index  Main.jsp index.html;
    }
 #index  index.html ;
# try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   #error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  #location = /50x.html {
  #  root   html;
  #}
```

Comment: Change `location /folder/` to `location /`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to rewrite the url, but to send the url to the correct folder. 
.well-known/acme-challenge is known to be a challenge for ssl certificates that are made automatically (lets'encrypt), so simply set the alias to the folder where your bot writes the "challenge" and you are good to go.

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    auth_basic          off;
    alias /directory/to/challenge;
    default_type text/plain;
}
```

That way it will "accept" and respond the challenge correctly

Even if you keep wanting to rewrite it, set a redirec to to domain/folder/$request_uri line:

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    return 301 http://$host/folder/$request_uri;
}
```